# Only keep the first N elements of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to only keep the first N (for example 10) elements of an array? I know there is `array_pop`, but is there a better, more elegant way?

Comment: Next time you need an array function: [PHP Array Functions in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) or [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice):

```
$b = array_slice($a, 0, 10);
$c = array_splice($a, 0, 10);
```

Note that `array_slice` copies the items of `$a` and returns them while `array_splice` does modify `$a` itself and only returns the items that have been removed from `$a`.